# Imports do not work and React files are not found

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, import

I have a big problem that often confuses me.
From time to time, while importing code, the import does not work and the development environment does not find the files. I work at IntelliJ IDEA.
To find a file, I first export it:

export let Filename =

and I import in the file necessary for me, but when I register a file name, ide for me does not look and it is necessary to write independently. But when I write the path to a file manually, I get the error that there is no such file. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try like import {FileName} from "index.js";

Comment: @HareshMakwana Unfortunately, with or without curly braces or with index.js - it does not matter, it does not import files, and also, if after the keyword "import" to register the first letter of the component, it does not look for it

Comment: not enough ifo to see what's wrong. What do you mean saying that files can't be found? what do the paths look like? please share screenshots